# Sharepoint Cert tests

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Are there any Sharepoint, SharePoint server certs that haven't retired? My company is still using SharePoint 2016 On-Prem and just a wee bit of SharePoint Online.

I tried looking for Sharepoint online certs too but no luck...

Can anyone help?

Comment: What kind of Certs are you looking for?

Comment: Anything SharePoint really... I was informed by my supervisor to search for a SP cert and I can't seem to find anything to help up my skill level.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to **Microsoft Certifications and Exams**, there is no currently available exam specific to SharePoint Server or Online products. Here is the only one exam related not expired yet by the way: [Exam SC-400: Microsoft Information Protection Administrator (Security exam beta).](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/certifications/exams/sc-400)

In addition, SharePoint Server 2016 will be reaching to its Mainstream End Date `07/13/2021` this year, so there probably will not be any renewed Certification on this product. You can keep an eye on the Microsoft Certifications program for new certificates on SPO.

For any other questions on Microsoft Certification program, you can ask a question in the forum here: https://trainingsupport.microsoft.com/en-us/mcp/forum